# ACF Post Object returning null

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m starting to get into WP dev and I’m having issues with ACF Post Object returning null and I’m not sure why.  I created a ACF with a location of Taxonomy is equal to Category Then the field is setup like…

- Field Name : recommended_resources
- Type: Post Object
- Filter by post type: Post
- Select multiple values: Yes
- Return Format: Post Object

Then in the post > category section I can edit the field and I select 3 posts.
Finally in my category.php I try and dumb the values like so,

```
echo '<pre>';
 var_dump(get_field('recommended_resources'));
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

and I get null
Any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of local DB
[image: Screenshot of local DB]

Comment: What do you get when using `print_r`?

Comment: Nothing at all shows up

Comment: Do you have access to database? Can you check that field value in the post_meta?

Comment: I'm using Local flywheel and when i click on Database > open adminer I see a few tables. I don't see post_meta, but i do see wp_postmeta is that where I should be looking? Sorry if that's not helpful

Comment: Yup, that's it - sorry I don't remember correct names ... I usually click on things automatically :P

Comment: So, I should be looking in wp_postmeta for "recommended_resources"? If so, I don't see it there. I'll post a screenshot of what I'm looking at.

Comment: No, I don't think this is the actual name. ACF does some name changing - can you go to the post with this field - inspect the field and see it's ID in HTML - that should be in the DB. Also I would search manually as the name of the field might be very close - you might be able to recognise it that way. We only want to see what value it has.

Comment: I've updated the post to show what I found in the database.

Comment: Answer posted - let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not pointing the `get_field` function to the correct post.
The field returns NULL because you want field `recommended_resources` of post NULL.

If you look at the ACF get_field documentation, you'll see that it requires `$id` of a post. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

If on a post page or in a post loop:

```
echo '<pre>';
 var_dump(get_field('recommended_resources', get_the_ID()));
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

just hardcoded:

```
$id = 216;

echo '<pre>';
 var_dump(get_field('recommended_resources', $id));
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

How it was tested:

```
add_shortcode('test_test','test_test');
function test_test() {

    $id = 216;

    $post_obj = get_field('object', $id);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($post_obj);
    echo '</pre>';

    foreach($post_obj as $post) {
        echo get_the_title( $post->ID ) . '<br>';
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far! I still can't get this to work, even when hardcoding the post id I still get null. I tried using 683.   I also tried checking if it exists like so and got nothing 
 <?php if (get_field('recommended_resources', 683)) :
            echo 'found something';
        else :
            echo 'nothing here';
        endif; ?>

Comment: Hey, no problem. I tested this solution and it did work. I got all the records.